# Does the phrase "on the sea" make this sentence ungrammatical?

Tags: grammar, phrases

"A fishing port was located south of the markets, on the sea."

I have read sentences like the one above, in which a more specific description is given using a phrase after a vague one has been stated.
Please, tell me what this grammatical technique is called so I can read on it. And does the phrase "on the sea" make the sentence ungrammatical?

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+town+on+the+sea%2Ca+town+on+the+coast%2Ca+town+on+the+shore&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20town%20on%20the%20sea%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20town%20on%20the%20coast%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20town%20on%20the%20shore%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20town%20on%20the%20sea%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20town%20on%20the%20coast%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20town%20on%20the%20shore%3B%2Cc0) showing that ***town on the sea*** is relatively uncommon compared to ***...coast*** or ***shore***.

Comment: ...and if you look at some of the actual examples, you'll see that it's often ***...on the sea-coast, ...the sea-shore, ...Sea of Galilee*** or similar anyway. But this isn't "grammar" - it's just a matter of what's ***idiomatically established***. And in this context, ***sea*** is indeed "established" (in that it's far from "unknown"), but for most people it's not usually their first choice of phrasing.

Comment: ...the far more common preposition is ***by** the sea*.

Comment: An exception is the UK (a tiny, tiny, proportion of the coastlines of English speaking countries), where Town-on-Sea, is not uncommon.

Comment: It is much easier to understand if you include the adjective phrase next to the word it modifies instead of placing it at the end of the sentence.  *A seaside fishing port was located south of the markets.*

Comment: In England, Bexhill-on-Sea and Shoreham-by-Sea are towns in West Sussex and East Sussex respectively.

Comment: I know there are many exceptions and both versions are grammatically correct, but given the choice I would say that towns were **by** the sea whilst boats were **on** the sea. You can have a town that is **on** the bay / coast / inlet / estuary etc since there is a land feature involved and it is understood that the town would be built on it.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't ungrammatical, but it may not be the best way to express what you want.

**On** the sea makes it sound as if it is floating, or on stilt supported platforms.

**By** the sea, or **On** the coast are better.

Comment: I disagree a bit - you can find numerous examples of "town/village/city on the sea" in Google Books.  It's slightly poetic and old-fashioned, IMO, but context makes it perfectly clear that whatever it is is not literally on top of the water.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I don't *think* that it's good practice for things other than places.